# Cant add Docker Support Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, docker, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS 2017. I have a web service and I want to add docker support to it. When I right click and open up the menu to add docker support it is greyed out. What causes it to be greyed out? How can I add docker support to my app?

*Side note I went up to the solution and added a new project (web app) and when it's done adding that new project I'm able to add docker support to it but still not able to add support to my other web service. Also both projects are targeting 
.net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Which runtimes and runtime versions are the two projects targeting?

Comment: .net framework 4.5.2

Comment: I believe you may need to re-run the installer to add the docker capabilities. It is one of the sub selections.

Comment: but it works on all new projects I added just not the original one. You think it still needs a re install

Answer (score 8):

Edit the .csproj file and search for "docker" - remove the following line:

```
<DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
```

Also delete the file "Dockerfile" which should be in the same folder as the .csproj file.

Comment: I took a look for what you said my csproj file doesn't have the word "docker" in it. Since the project was created before Docker support came to Visual Studio.

Comment: Open Explorer and search the solution folder for "docker" - if you find anything called "dockerfile" or similar, delete (or rename) them.

Failing that, it might be easier to create a fresh project and copy all of the files across.

Comment: Sadly this didnt work for me :( the button is still greyed out

Answer (score 2):

Try double-checking your .csproj, .sln, and solution and project folders for any references to Docker. There have been a few times where I have run into this, usually caused by adding, removing, and trying to re-add Docker support. Clearing out the Dockerfile in the project folder along any other Docker stuff in the solution solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

That could be because of your solution already contain docker-compose with dockerignore and docker-compose.yml.

If you want to add it again, Try to remove it and check.

[image]